# What's the Correct Syntax to query a Database in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to query my database to give me the ID numbers of all entries with a math score of 50 and below but can't seem to get the syntax right.

This is what I tried, I don't get any error, it just doesn't work.

```
<?php

if ($dumby->ajax()) {
    // Scan database, find any score lower than 50, then copy the ID for that row.
    $output_array[] = "";
    $output = "branson";

    $trailers = DB::table('dataentries')->where('Eng_Algebra', '=<', '50')->get();
    if ($trailers) {
        foreach ($trailers as $key => $trailers) {
            array_push($output_array, $trailers->Eng_Algebra);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `<=`, not `=<`

Comment: it might work in this situation (because of scope), but you should avoid the double variable `$trailers`

Comment: That should throw an error, maybe you don't have reporting enabled.